# MySQL count different value in same table

Tags: mysql

I am working on a database right now, and I am trying to select some special data. 
so the table looks like this.

```
name  title  type
```

Type is including two different value, "book" and "paper".

And this is the result I would like to get

```
name       book  paper
person A   0     1
person B   1     2
person C   0     5
```

What is the best way to write the query it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'book'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS book,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'paper' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS paper
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    name;
```

Comment: Is there any way doing it without using case

Comment: You may use `SUM(IF(type = 'book', 1, 0))` as an alternative.